# How to get Eclipse Package Explorer Action Bars

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

i need to retrieve the Package Explorer action bars to set a GlobalAction (setGlobalActionHandler). I'm using Eclipse 3.6.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but [this old 2006 thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg08912.html) might still present the right principle:

> Certain standard menu entries can be shared among several views and editors.
>   So called global or retargetable actions and include tools like undo/redo, cut/copy/paste, print, find, delete, and more. (look at class `IWorkbenchActionFactory`).
>   Each view or editor is allowed to contribute a handler for these actions; when a new part becomes active, its handler takes control of that action. A view has to register its global action handlers in the `createPartControl` method:

```
   IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
   actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
      IWorkbenchActionFactory.COPY,
      myCopyAction);
```

> In order to override copy/paste implementation of Package Explorer you need to get its `ViewSite`.

Comment: I don´t know hoy to get the Package Explorer ViewState, i've tried through my plugin get the workbench then the active workbench window and then the active page, but i'm always getting null. It there any other wat to get the ViewSite of the Package explorer?

Comment: Did you get the viewPart first? `IWorkbenchPage page = myPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(JavaUI.ID_PACKAGES);`

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the way i did it but "page" is always null. Is there another way?